# Convert a list of integers to list of strings

Tags: python, list

I am trying to convert a list with integers values in a list with strings

```
a=[[1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

And I would like to get something like that

```
b=[['1', '2', '4', '3', '2', '1']]
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: ah sorry, python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about python, here is the solution:

```
b = [str(int) for int in a]
```

Notice that this will work if a is a list, from your question it seems that you are dealing with a list of list (given the double square brackets)

Comment: Forgot to add that this called list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python, you may use a list comprehension:

```py
a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = [str(x) for x in a]
print(b)  # ['1', '2', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = [str(i) for i in a]
```

You can find further details here : https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter6_comprehensions.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).